# What Character Encoding Is it?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, character

Hi I have some DBF files, containing old school records (grades, names etc.). I wanted to migrate them into new database, but can't find the right charset. I ran all JAVA supported charsets, but none of them returned right characters for bytes I identified.
It's Latvian text. I'm used to UTF8, windows-1257, but haven't seen anything like this. It should be like this:
0xC6 for ā
0xF0 for Ē
0xF1 for ē
0xD2 for č
0xF5 for ļ
0xFD for š
0x61 for a
0x31 for 1
What character encoding it is?

Comment: This combination of mappings does not match any of the encodings known to Python.  See e.g. https://cdn.rawgit.com/tripleee/8bit/master/encodings.html

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found the right encoding. It was a standard in Latvia till 1992, but still was used till 2010 for bank reports by law. Many DOS programs was using it in Latvia.
It's **RST 1040-90**
http://dl.tilde.lv/download/TildesBirojs/HTML.Help/index.html?pielikums_b.htm